# how to make a custom function NOT recalculate in Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, custom-function

I find that each time i log in. The heavy functions I have do recalculate.  IN particular it is functions including UrlFetch that recalculate and make 100s of calls to the url when I log in. I would rather just rely on the data I drew last time. Is there a way to block (haphazard) recalculation?

Comment: I realize that most people have the OPPOSITE problem. of trying to force recalculation...

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Related   
https://stackoverflow.com/q/32797710/1595451  
https://stackoverflow.com/q/48427160/1595451   
https://stackoverflow.com/q/43519541/1595451   
https://stackoverflow.com/q/46186526/1595451

Comment: Thank you @Ruben, Hmm. so it seems that this is impossible. Function recalculation cannot be disabled. I understand the workarounds are (1.) to make a "switch" input to the function, which while in "dont update state" would make the function return nothing. Is there a way to stop a function entirely? since if it returned nothing it would overwrite (2) custom functions that are in-sheet , of the type =SUM etc, in a cell,  those will recalc no matter what. While, clearly, functions that are triggered otherwise - not in cells - would not. AM I understanding correctly?

Comment: Yes, you are understanding correctly. I suggest you to edit your question or answer with what you have learned so far.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for Ruben's help:

Function recalculation cannot be disabled.

the workarounds are (1.) to make a "switch" input to the function, which while in "don't update state" would make the function return nothing.  If the function is of the "=FUNCTION()", in-cell, type, the empty return will overwrite your data, unfortunately. :/

(2) Functions that are in-cell, as above, will recalc no matter what. While, clearly, functions that are triggered otherwise - not in cells - would not.

What I will probably do is to write non-in-cell functions that drop the formulas into the cells. These will run, and re-run, only when pressing a button

Comment: Use time triggers or buttons with setValues() instead