# Remove permission to one spreadsheet to pull data from another spreadsheet with IMPORTRANGE

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

With IMPORTRANGE **SpreadSheets A, B, C, etc** Requests access to  pull data from **SpreadSheet 1** (pic 1). Example:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("SpreadSheet 1"; "Sheet!A1")
```

[image]

I want to remove access (revoke permission) from **Spreadsheet A** to pull data from **Spreadsheet 1** (pic 2) undo that allow access on the pic 1, to revoke permission to **Spreadsheet A** to pull data from **Spreadsheet 1**

[image]

It is just an example to simplify, because in reality I have over 200 spreadsheets connecting to 1 (actually 2) database spreadsheets, that is why I want to revoke permissions, there is a limit on how many spreadsheets can access one spreadsheet and I have reached that limit many times already

Picture of real spreadsheet to help understand part of my code, script will run on same spreadsheet that requests access

[image]

I may be wrong but an old script I had, I think used to work

```
function removePermission() 
{
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ss_c = ss.getSheetByName('Config');

  var currentSheetId = ss.getId();
  var targetId = "";

  if (ss_c.getRange("B6").getValue() == 1)
  {
    targetId = ss_c.getRange("D6").getValue();
  } 
  else if (ss_c.getRange("B6").getValue() == 2) 
  {
    targetId = ss_c.getRange("D7").getValue();
  }

  var currentFile = DriveApp.getFileById(currentSheetId);
  var targetFile = DriveApp.getFileById(targetId);
  var targetPermissions = targetFile.getPermissions();

  for (var i = 0; i < targetPermissions.length; i++) 
  {
    var permission = targetPermissions[i];
    if (permission.getType() == "user" && permission.hasAccess()) 
    {
      currentFile.removeEditor(permission.getEmail()); // or the next one
//    targetFile.removeEditor(permission.getEmail());
    }
  }
}
```

But now it displays error `TypeError: targetFile.getPermissions is not a function`

So I tried to modify with what I searched:

```
function test() 
{
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ss_c = ss.getSheetByName('Config');

  var currentSheetId = ss.getId();
  var targetId = "";

  if (ss_c.getRange("B6").getValue() == 1) 
  {
    targetId = ss_c.getRange("D6").getValue();
  } 
  else if (ss_c.getRange("B6").getValue() == 2) 
  {
    targetId = ss_c.getRange("D7").getValue();
  }

  var currentFile = DriveApp.getFileById(currentSheetId);
  var targetFile = DriveApp.getFileById(targetId);
  var targetEditors = targetFile.getEditors();
  var currentEditors = currentFile.getEditors();
  var activeUserEmail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

  for (var i = 0; i < targetEditors.length; i++) {
    var editor = targetEditors[i];
    var editorEmail = editor.getEmail();
    
    // Check if the editor exists in the current file before removing
    if (editorEmail !== activeUserEmail && currentEditors.some(e => e.getEmail() === editorEmail)) {
      targetFile.removeEditor(editorEmail);
    }
  }
}
```

This passes, but doesn't work.

I'm not familiar how editors work exactly in this case and searching I couldn't find related problems and solutions.

I'm the owner and only user, not sure but it is related to files not users.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `i want to remove access, from sheets that im going to delete`. Can I ask you about the detail of it? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: ok,   lets say Sheets A, B and C connect to pull  data  from Sheet 1, I want to remove access from sheet A from 1 but keep B and C accessing it

Comment: getId gets sheet i want to delete and have access removed  from  targetId,   i will  run that script on sheets i will delete, not the target

Comment: Thank you for repling. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your goal from `lets say Sheets A, B and C connect to pull data from Sheet 1, I want to remove access from sheet A from 1 but keep B and C accessing it` and `getId gets sheet i want to delete and have access removed from targetId, i will run that script on sheets i will delete, not the target`.

Comment: What dows `lets say Sheets A, B and C connect to pull data from Sheet 1` mean? I cannot understand the differences between Sheets A, B, C, and 1. You want to use 4 sheets A, B, C and 1 in a Google Spreadsheet? Can I ask you about the detail of your goal? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: let me try to make this as simple as possible Sheet A B and C request to pull data from Sheet 1,  like in the picture on my post,  all 3 have access allowed, then I want  to undo (remove) that permission from Sheet A,  if i need sheet A to pull data from Sheet 1 again,  I will have to allow access again, repeating what i did in the picture, but permissions for sheet B and C remains

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. I cannot understand between `access allowed` and each sheet (sheets A, B, C, and 1). What are the sheets A, B, C, and 1?

Comment: Although, this is just my guess, for example, your "sheets A, B, C, and 1" mean 4 independent Google Spreadsheets which is not each sheet in a Google Spreadsheet? And, in your situation, the values are retrieved from 3 Google Spreadsheets "A", "B" and "C" to the Google Spreadsheet "1" using `IMPORTRANGE`. And, you want to revoke the access permission for retrieving the values from Google Spreadsheet "A". Is my understanding correct?

Comment: im sorry for the confusion, it was totally my fault for not providing correct information and mixing sheets and spreadsheets,  i edited post to  include pictures and clarify information, but yea, 4 independent spreadsheets, although values are retrieved from Spreadsheet "1" (DATABASE) to Spreadsheets "A", "B" and "C", thanks for your patience and im sorry for my mistake, i hope you can understand it now

Comment: Make a copy of Spreadsheet1 and delete Spreadsheet1?

Comment: forget about deleting,  etc i was trying to explain with more details than needed, lets say,  one SS can allow 500 other SS, i dont know, but i know there is a limit, and  im  not sure how those  file  permissions work,  if you delete one SS that is using one of those spots,  it doesnt free (vacancy) that spot,  ive tested it,  to test if script work it would mean same SS having to ask access again while other SS remain with access,  again i dont know how internally permissions work, that is why im over explaining, img 2 with arrows should illustrate what i want to achieve

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your reply, I proposed a workaround as an answer. Please confirmit. If that was not useful and I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You have a Google Spreadsheet including the authorized `IMPORTRANGE` functions.
- You want to revoke the several authorizations for `IMPORTRANGE` from Spreadsheet.

#### Issue and workaround:

I checked the method for directly revoking the authorization of `IMPORTRANGE` from Spreadsheet. Unfortunately, I couldn't find the method. But, we have already known when an endpoint is used, the authorization process can be run by a script. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67280686/7108653) I thouoght that this might be able to be used in your situation as a workaround. The flow of this workaround is as follows.

1. Copy the original Spreadsheet.
2. Authorize `IMPORTRANGE` except for the Spreadsheet you want to revoke.

By this flow, a Google Spreadsheet is obtained by revoking the specific Spreadsheets you want.

But, in this workaround, the Spreadsheet ID is changed from the original one, because the original Spreadsheet is copied. So, I'm not sure whether this is useful for your actual situation. So, I just propose this workaround.

When the above flow is reflected in a sample script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of the original Spreadsheet, and set `spreadsheetIdsOfdeletePermission` and save the script.

```js
function myFunction() {
  // Please set the Spreadsheet IDs you want to revoke the authorization of "IMPORTRANGE".
  const spreadsheetIdsOfdeletePermission = ["###spreadsheetId1###", "###spreadsheetId2###",,,];

  // Retrieve original Spreadsheet.
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ssId = ss.getId();
  const orgFile = DriveApp.getFileById(ssId);
  const parent = orgFile.getParents().next();

  // Copy original Spreadsheet.
  const tempFile = orgFile.makeCopy(ss.getName() + "_new", parent);
  const tempFileId = tempFile.getId();

  // Authorize "IMPORTRANGE" except for "spreadsheetIdsOfdeletePermission"
  const tempSS = SpreadsheetApp.open(tempFile);
  const token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  const reqs = tempSS.createTextFinder("=IMPORTRANGE").matchFormulaText(true).findAll().reduce((ar, r) => {
    const id = r.getFormula().match(/^\=IMPORTRANGE\("(.*?)"/)[1].split("/")[5];
    if (!spreadsheetIdsOfdeletePermission.includes(id)) {
      const url = `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${tempFileId}/externaldata/addimportrangepermissions?donorDocId=${id}`;
      ar.push({ url, method: "post", headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }, muteHttpExceptions: true });
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);
  if (reqs.length == 0) return;
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(reqs);
  res.forEach(r => {
    if (r.getResponseCode() != 200) {
      console.log(r.getContentText());
    }
  });
}
```

- When this script is run, the original Spreadsheet is copied and a new Spreadsheet is created by revoking the specific authorizations of "IMPORTRANGE".

#### Note:

- Unfortunately, I cannot know your actual situation. So, if an error occurs related to the continuous requests, `UrlFetchApp.fetch` instead of `UrlFetchApp.fetchAll` might be required to be used in a loop with `Utilities.sleep`.

#### References:

- [How to allow access for importrange function via apps script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28038768)
- [fetchAll(requests)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchallrequests)

Comment: I really thank you and appreciate  your effort, going beyond and above with a workaround, but what I needed was a way to revoke that permission,  im going to leave it unanswered in case someone find way and post, that being said,  I liked your workaround,  understood what you tried to do, creative and Im going to use part of that in other scripts,, thank you for your time and i apologize for the confusion I caused not describing things properly

Comment: @Bruno Carvalho Thank you for replying. About `but what I needed was a way to revoke that permission`, although I have been trying to directly achieve your goal, unfortunately, I couldn't find it. I think that this is my poor skill. I have to apologize for this. From this situation, I proposed a workaround. I deeply apologize that my workaround was not useful for your situation. But, I think that this workaround might be useful for other users. So, I would like to leave this answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no documented way to revoke the permissions granted to `importrange()`. The access slot will remain reserved even if you remove the import formula or delete the destination spreadsheet.

The easiest workaround is to use **File > Share > Share with others** to share the spreadsheet as *"anyone with link"* and remove all named user shares you can. For additional workarounds, see [Quota/limitations on importrange()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77966638/13045193).